# Change background color after selecting item with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a search bar and I want when I select item to change background color of that search bar. I have to do that with jQuery and CSS.

Background without select tag

[image: background without select tag]

I have to change background color of search bar when tag is selected

[image: i have to change background color of search bar when tag is selected]

My name of the class is `select2-choices`.

Can anyone help me how to write this code?

Comment: Show the code mate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Jquery selectors.
Detect the option on the search bar being clicked, then set the background color of your control.

```
$(".select2-choices").click(function () {
            $("#MySearchBar).css({ "background-color": "White" });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(".select2-choices").click(function () {
        var bar = $("#MySearchBar);
        bar.setAttribute("style","background-color:White");
});`

Comment: this will override all previously set inline-style - also `setAttribute` is a method for DOM elements, not jQuery-objects